# robots.txt disallow slash missing when requested via browser

Tags: robots.txt

My robots.txt looks like follows, when i edit it:

```
# no indexing at all:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But when i request it via the browser, it contains no comment, which is ok, but also the slash in the disallow directive is missing, what inverts the purposed effect:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Consequently, robots.txt testing services like 
https://de.onpage.org/free-tools/robots-txt/
say google is allowed to crawl...

Why is that slash missing?

Comment: _“Why is that slash missing?”_ – how should we know, without knowing _anything_ about your system?

Comment: Is it a static txt file? Served directly (without parsing/modification by your webserver)? Try making any change at all and place it on your server. Can you see that change? Any caching in front of it?

Comment: My two guesses would be 1) Possibly your web root directory is not where you think it is, and you edited the wrong file, or 2) Maybe your server has a rewrite rule that serves some other file in place of your robots.txt file.

Comment: Gosh thanks @plasticinsect... 1) for me.